# What is this succulent plant with pointed leaves that looks like a cross between agave and aloe?

Tags: identification, succulents, aloe

I am looking to add this plant to my garden, but have no idea what it is called.

When I searched "pointy plants" it shows up under succulents, agave & aloe.

[image: pointed plant]

Answer (score 4):

I would like to take a stab at this ID.  I love succulents and desert plants! This is gorgeous and I believe it is Agave 'Blue Glow'... Thought I'd send this link... Hey, but I could be wrong! [Agave and Aloe](http://myvalleynews.com/homeandgarden/healthy-beautiful-gardens-all-about-agaves-and-aloes/)